# Java saving huffman encoded text to file

Tags: java, huffman-code

I'm working on a huffman compression and decompression application in java. So far I got the encoding and decoding working. It converts a big input text to it's encoded binary text. This is a String of 1's and 0's. For example:

String originaltext = "Hello I am trying to program a huffman application and..."

String encodedtext = "1100001110001111011010100110100110...." It's a pretty long string.

Now I want to save the string to a file as binary file to reduce the size. But when I try do this, the size will be way bigger then the original text size. Instead I need the size smaller then the original file size. After saving the encodedtext to a file I need to read the binary file back in and convert it to the encodedText string to deconvert it with my huffmantree method.

How can I save the binary string to a binary file which size is then smaller then the original size? And how do read the file in and convert the binary code to the encodedString text?

Comment: "But when I try do this, the size will be way bigger then the original text size." - Are you writing the represented binary or the actual `String`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem in saving Huffman Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615877/problem-in-saving-huffman-code)

Comment: I guess the actual String, how can I convert it to a binary string?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're writing your string of 1 and 0 as a string, which will result in 1 byte per 1 or 0.

You need to convert those 1 and 0 to bytes (i.e. convert groups of eight 1 or 0 into 1 byte and write those bytes.

**EDIT**

See answer by `6502` to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615877/problem-in-saving-huffman-code) for some code to convert the 1s and 0s to bytes.

Comment: How can I convert the 1 and 0's to bytes?

Comment: See the possible duplicate link above. There you find a simple algorithm.